# brownie compile gives File outside of allowed directories

Tags: solidity, blockchain, web3.py, nft, brownie

```
PS E:\NFT-DEMO> brownie compile
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.6
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:6:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: i am getting compiler error

Comment: Can you post your `brownie-config.yaml` in your question

Answer (score 0):

In your brownie-config.yaml file make sure you have the following code:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
```

Comment: well i have contracts@1.1.1

Comment: now iam getttng this error:

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:6:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

Comment: can u solve my query

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code of your brownie-config and python script